# getdomainname() returns bad address under MPI (testing PETSc library)

Tags: c, macos, mpi, mpich, unistd.h

I am attempting to install PETSc-3.2 on my laptop (MacBook Pro 10.5.8, MPICH2-1.1) and am running into some difficulty when running the tests: it errors out from a system call to `getdomainname()` which returns a bad address.

```
[-1]PETSC ERROR: --------------------- Error Message ------------------
[-1]PETSC ERROR: Error in system call!
[-1]PETSC ERROR: getdomainname()!
[-1]PETSC ERROR: ------------------------------------------------------
```

To investigate, I wrote the following test codes to check the functionality of `getdomainname()` with and without MPI:

Single processor:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *name;
  int namelen = CHAR_MAX;
  name = (char*) calloc (namelen,sizeof(char));
  int err = getdomainname(name,namelen);
  printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));
  printf("Domain name: %s\n",name);
  return err;
}
```

Parallel:

```
/* Headers */
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

  int myrank;
  char *mpi_name;
  int mpi_namelen = MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME;
  mpi_name = (char*) calloc (mpi_namelen,sizeof(char));

  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myrank);
  int mpi_err = MPI_Get_processor_name(mpi_name,&mpi_namelen);
  printf("MPI_Get_processor_name [%d]: %s\n",mpi_err,mpi_name);

  char *name;
  int namelen = CHAR_MAX;
  name = (char*) calloc (namelen,sizeof(char));
  int err = getdomainname(name,namelen);
  printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));
  printf("Domain name: %s\n",name);
  return err;

  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

The single processor code works without issue, and the parallel code gets the correct name for the processors, but returns bad address on the call to `getdomainname()` even if running  with `mpirun -np 1`.

Has anyone run into a problem like this before? Is there some kind of configuration for `mpirun` I need to do so that the domain name is set for each process spawned by MPI?  Thanks in advance!

## Update:

For those running into this problem with PETSc, compile with the option `--with-debugging=0`. It seems that in some of the PETSc debugging messages etc. they use a call to `getdomainname()` rather than `MPI_Get_processor_name()`. Compiling without debugging disables this branch in the library.

Comment: Is this an x86_64 or an IA-32 system? Could it be the case that MPI compilers and the non-MPI test are for different architectures?

Comment: Good call, I didn't even think about that!  My MPI compiler automatically uses `-m64`. I re-compiled my single-processor code with  `-m64` and it stopped working... is tehre a way to fix this or should I just be compiling everything without `-m64`? Put this in an answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a more recent version of MPICH2, 1.1 is very old.  Current versions shouldn't be adding any `-m32`/`-m64` arguments to `mpicc` unless you ask it to.  (I'm not sure older versions did this either, but it's possible)